# Scheduled local Notification show in Alert Box if application is running else send local notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-local-notification

In my flutter I have implemented `flutter_local_notifications`. I am using scheduled notification and it is working fine but what I want is when Application is running it should show scheduled notification in alert box instead of sending notification and when app not running then send actual notification. Note: I am using `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule` to schedule the notification and it's working fine.

I Just want to show scheduled notification in alert box when application is running.

here is my code

```
Future<void> _scheduleNotification(DateTime initialTime, String title, String body) async {
    final tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(initialTime.subtract(const Duration(minutes: 5)), tz.local);
    final notificationId = initialTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch~/100000;
    final currentTime = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);// Check if scheduledDate is in the past
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(currentTime)) {
      return;
    }
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final notificationEnabled = prefs.getBool('notificationEnabled') ?? true;
    if (!notificationEnabled) {
      return;
    }
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id', 'channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      showWhen: true,
    );

    const iosNotificationDetail = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentSound: true,
      presentBadge: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,iOS: iosNotificationDetail);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId, // Use the hashed value as the Notification ID
      title, // Notification Title
      body, // Notification Body
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
```